# writing the parsed text onto the textarea

Tags: java, pdfbox, netbeans-8.1

Im trying to convert the pdf document to txt format and im trying to display it onto the text area, on pressing the OK button. The UI was created in netbeans 8.1.. There are no errors but im not getting the output.. im attaching the code below..

```
 private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   

    try{ 
       String s = null;
       StringBuilder sb;
       File file = new File("D.pdf");
       PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(file);
       PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
       String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
       textArea1.setText(parsedText);
      }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e)
     }
}
```

this is the error that i get when i click the button
run:
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

Comment: Have you run your code in a debugger and inspected the `String parsedText`?

Comment: yes..i tried printing the value onto the console...nothing is getting printed..

Comment: Thus, your PDF does not seem to contain extractable text. You may want to share the PDF for analysis.

Comment: i tried with different pdfs..but it still is not wrking...this code works as a program alone, but it is not wrking wen i integrate it with the GUI(text area and button)

Comment: Probably the GUI needs to be invalidated / repainted / whatever; it looks like a gui toolkit issue, so you might want to add tags accordingly.

Comment: but if you try to print "hii" instead of parsedText in the textarea, it works properly..

Comment: You currently ignore any exception caught. As you say text stripping as a separate job works and also showing some constant string, there might be some exception thrown by the code and ignored by you. Thus, please log any exception with its respective stack trace.

Comment: Could it be that the extracted text starts with a few blank lines? Try scrolling in the field.

Comment: it doesnt start with blank lines..I get the output when i run this in a normal pgm.

Comment: Now the only way to solve this is to get all the information. Please include all the java of what you're doing in the question (or upload it somewhere), and upload a PDF that brings the effect.

Comment: @Ria Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is the error that i get when i click the button
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
>     at textarea1.append(textarea1.java:22)
>     at clickdb.okActionPerformed(clickdb.java:97)
> ```

This indicates that there is an issue in your `textarea1` class, not in your PDFBox usage. You might want to inspect that class or post it for further analysis.

It is quite surprising, though, that the stack trace indicates that you call `append`, not `setText` as in the code in your question. If that stack trace was from a test run with a slightly different code, please update your information and include both the current code and a current stack trace.